# Rename [recettear] → [recettear-an-item-shops-tale]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tag for [*Recettear: An Item Shop's Tale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recettear:_An_Item_Shop%27s_Tale) can be renamed, thanks to the 35 character tag limit.

- [recettear](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recettear) → [recettear-an-item-shops-tale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recettear-an-item-shops-tale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

[recettear](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recettear) → [recettear-an-item-shops-tale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recettear-an-item-shops-tale)